# Parsing IP Address to string doesn't work for some reason

Tags: c#, ip-address

it's telling me this

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: An invalid IP address was specified"

```
IPAddress ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse(richTextBox1.Text);
```

that's the code, richTextBox1 is the default name for a rich textbox.

i don't know why this isn't working

Edit: i'm really dumb i parsed the wrong textbox

Comment: What's in `richTextBox1.Text`?

Comment: We can't know without seeing the text you're trying to parse.

Comment: @IllidanS4 i tried my IP and i tried 127.0.0.1, neither worked

Comment: @cubrr i tried my IP and i tried 127.0.0.1, neither worked

Comment: You should probably set a breakpoint there and try to look what is in `richTextBox1.Text`

Comment: @mattytommo 127.0.0.1 works because it is a valid IPv4 address.

Comment: So based on your edit, you're not seeing this problem anymore?

Comment: @JamesThorpe yea sorry for wasting time, i just parsed the wrong textbox. textbox1 instead of textbox2. yea...i should start giving stuff meaningful names

Comment: @Muffinator Can you answer your own question so it can be closed?

Comment: @KABoissonneault yea i'll be able to in one minute. sorry for the hassle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPAddress.Parse does not accept spaces or other characters in the string. Use string.Trim to eliminate such characters and it should work:

```
var result = IpAddress.Parse(richTextBox1.Text.Trim());
```